# Not able to connect to mongodb when start node server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, compiler-errors, connection

I am trying to run my node app locally on my VM.

When I am running command:

`sudo NODE_ENV= XYZ PORT=80 node server/app.js`

I'm getting error:

> /node_modules/mongo-oplog/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/mongo_client.js:378
>             throw err
>                   ^ Error: connection closed
>       at null. (/node_modules/mongo-oplog/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:605:24)
>       at emit (events.js:92:17)
>       at null. (/node_modules/mongo-oplog/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection_pool.js:155:15)
>       at emit (events.js:98:17)
>       at Socket. (//node_modules/mongo-oplog/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection.js:528:12)
>       at Socket.emit (events.js:95:17)

My mongoDB is running fine and I can connect to local db with robomongo.

Any help would be highly appreciated on this.

Comment: Can you show code responsible for connecting to MongoDB instance in your node.js file?

Comment: Absolutely needed the app.js with the connection string

Comment: why not use the mongoose plugin? its super simple to use, that might remove the error